# mongodb fix the array position

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, codeigniter

I have below collection called category it has document with subdocument. I have issue with the array position of array or document.
1. category document when I created/inserted first time.

```
 { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("562f655fb725bc7c0e7a55a1"), 
    "created" : "2015-10-27 17:21:59", 
    "cate" : "Kids", 
    "status" : "1" 
    "subcat" : [
        {"caId" : "2309f2d7be1d9072e5d84cfae30346f4", "catename" : "Toy","updateDate" : "2015-10-28 09:37:10", "status" : 2 },
        {"caId" : "8e00551b75c2410f6983920b8b81a595", "catename" : "Baby Care", "updateDate" : "2015-10-28 09:37:14", "status" : 2 },
        {"caId" : "46efb60afb05f9af23271253c6ab6557" "catename" : "Hiar Care", "updateDate" : "2015-10-28 09:40:35", "status" : "1"},
        {"caId" : "62b9d21376a61b4477a2ea8644d476cb" "catename" : "Baby Bath", "updateDate" : "2015-10-28 09:41:15", "status" : "2"}
    ],
}
```

2. I use the update query in codeigniter framework as bellow

   ```
   // updated caId=>62b9d21376a61b4477a2ea8644d476cb with  catename =>Baby Bathroom

   function updateCaste($id,$catId, $data){
       $this->mongo_db->set(array("subcat.$" => $data));
       $this->mongo_db->where(array("_id" => new MongoId($religiousId),"subcat.caId" => $id)); 
       $this->mongo_db->update(category); 
   }
   ```
3. When I check my array on shell script then its get rearrange. like below

   ```
   { 
       "_id" : ObjectId("562f655fb725bc7c0e7a55a1"), 
       "subcat" : [
           {"caId" : "2309f2d7be1d9072e5d84cfae30346f4", "catename" : "Toy","updateDate" : "2015-10-28 09:37:10", "status" : 2 },
           {"caId" : "8e00551b75c2410f6983920b8b81a595", "catename" : "Baby Care", "updateDate" : "2015-10-28 09:37:14", "status" : 2 },
           {"caId" : "46efb60afb05f9af23271253c6ab6557" "catename" : "Hiar Care", "updateDate" : "2015-10-28 09:40:35", "status" : "1"},
           { "catename" : "Baby Bathroom", "updateDate" : "2015-10-28 09:41:15", "status" : "2","caId" : "62b9d21376a61b4477a2ea8644d476cb"}
       ],
       "created" : "2015-10-27 17:21:59", 
       "cate" : "Kids", 
       "status" : "1" 
   }
   ```

but after update I want 1. array should be same only the "catename" : "Baby Bathroom" change in that array.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-edit-update-and-delete-data-in-mongodb-with-codeigniter/

Comment: can you clear bit more??

Comment: @Abdulla  As you can see the both array and its sequence. first array was actual position of array and the sequence. when I'm try trying to update the caId=>62b9d21376a61b4477a2ea8644d476cb catename Baby Bath to Baby Bathroom then the position of array and the sequence change.

Comment: @Ricky Thanks.. it help me to find ans

Comment: You are most welcome cheers!